# How to get date from database but retaining drop down calendar at the same time?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I would like to ask, what is the proper way to call the date inserted previously to the database by user? This is because, this part of code I used for edit form function, so retaining the calendar dropdown is a must. The calendar dropdown is working but it doesn't show the previous value that has been inserted and if user submit without changing the date, it will automatically set to 01-01-1970.

Bellow is my code for calling the date from database

```html
<div class="form-group row" id="projectstartdate1">
  <label for="projectstartdate" class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Project Phase Start Date : </label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input type="date" name="project_start_date" value="<?php echo date(" d-m-Y ", strtotime($row['project_start_date'])); ?>" id="project_start_date" class="form-control" />
  </div>

  <label for="projectenddate" class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Estimated Project Phase End Date : </label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input type="date" name="project_end_date" value="<?php echo date(" d-m-Y ", strtotime($row['project_end_date'])); ?>" id="project_end_date" class="form-control" />
  </div>
</div>
```

and this is how it looks like

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to solve this?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want year-month-date for it to populate so change it to Y-m-d. Like this:

```
<div class="form-group row" id="projectstartdate1">
  <label for="projectstartdate" class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Project Phase Start Date : </label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input type="date" name="project_start_date" value="<?php echo date(" Y-m-d ", strtotime($row['project_start_date'])); ?>" id="project_start_date" class="form-control" />
  </div>

  <label for="projectenddate" class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Estimated Project Phase End Date : </label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input type="date" name="project_end_date" value="<?php echo date(" Y-m-d ", strtotime($row['project_end_date'])); ?>" id="project_end_date" class="form-control" />
  </div>
</div>
```